# OpenVPN strange behavior

Tags: freebsd, openvpn

I have a KVM VPS for my personal VPN. Server running on FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p1 with OpenVPN 2.4.0, and ipfw kernel nat.
Direct connection speed between me and VPS ~10-12 Mbps.
Via tunnel speed is ~1.6-5 Mbps (which enough for me).

This tunnel is for web surfing. When I download file from server via tunnel everything fine. But when I try to open some web page, speed is 2-7kbps!! **EXCEPT** youtube! Youtube always works fast and shows videos in 1080p with no freezes.

I tried different combinations of tcp/udp, cipers, sndbuf/rcvbuf, tun-mtu/mssfix, comp-lzo/compress lz4-v2/no compress, different TAP drivers, Windows 7 64/Ubuntu with no luck.

OpenVPN server conf:

```
port 3344
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert gate.crt
key gate.key
dh dh.pem
server 10.80.50.0 255.255.255.240
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
route 10.80.50.0 255.255.255.240
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.80.50.1"
keepalive 10 120
tls-authta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
max-clients 3
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
log         /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 6
askpass keyp
auth-nocache
sndbuf 393216
rcvbuf 393216
push "sndbuf 393216"
push "rcvbuf 393216"
```

Client conf

```
dev tun
proto udp
remote remove_vps 3344
client
resolv-retry infinite
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
remote-cert-tls server
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
askpass keyp
auth-nocache
```

IPFW:

```
allow ip from any to any via lo0
nat 1 ip from 10.80.50.6 to any out via vtnet0
nat 1 ip from any to $wanip in via vtnet0
allow ip from any to any via tun0
allow ip from any to any
deny log logamount 5 ip from any to any
deny ip from any to any
```

Can somebody help me to figure out where is the problem ?